# Altium Designer project version control

Tags: altium

I am learning [Altium Designer](https://www.altium.com/) and I've controling the project with [Arch Linux Subversion server](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Subversion). I've made some changes in the project's sheets and when I try to [Commit Whole Project](https://www.altium.com/documentation/17.1/display/ADES/VersionControl_Dlg-CommitToVersionControl((Commit+to+Version+Control))_AD), I get following situation:
[image: Commit Screenshot]
Now, as we can see, there is unversioned 'PCB_Project1.Dat' file. Is this file mandatory for non-error project import from `Subversion` or it **must be added to version control**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience the .dat file does not need to be placed in version control. I believe it's just basic component information and is updated whenever you generate a BOM.

Take a look at [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/159220/which-files-to-version-control-for-an-altium-pcb-project) for more information about what files you can ignore when committing a project to version control.